# After updating to iOS11 my searchBar behaves strange

Tags: swift, tableview, ios11, searchbar

After updating to iOS11 my searchBar behaves very strange. When activated, it jumps to the top of screen. It works as it should, as before but of course I want it to stay in place. I have tried a lot of solutions from googling this behavior but nothing helps. Do anyone have the same problem? And what did you do to solve this?

[searchBar in place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDu1K.png)

[searchBar jumped to top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WCoV.png)

```
var searchController: UISearchController!


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Setup the Search Controller
            searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
            searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
            searchController.searchBar.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true
            searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            walkaboutTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
            searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = matildaLightBlue
            searchController.searchBar.clipsToBounds = true
            searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 2
            searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding search controller instance into navigation item instead of table header view helps me to solve similar issue in my project.

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
   navigationItem.searchController = searchController
} else {
   tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}
```

[navigationItem.searchController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2897305-searchcontroller)

[navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2897296-hidessearchbarwhenscrolling)

Comment: thanks for the reply but its still not working. In fact, when using this code there is no searchBar at all...
If I declare the "var searchController: UISearchController!" inside the viewDidLoad it stays in place, but then I cant reach searchController from other part of the code.

Comment: Could you please try to initialize searchController as constant in your controller ?

`let searchController  = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)`
Also - you can download a good sample code project [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html) to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Ruslan Kolosovskyi's answer is really good. In addition if you want the search bar to be more accessible:

```
    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
       navigationItem.searchController = searchController

       navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    } else {
       tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
```